# How to set Visual Studio to AVOID "VC++ fatal error LNK1168: cannot open filename.exe for writing"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

READ VERY CAREFULLY BEFORE FLAGGING AS A DUPLICATE QUESTION.

I've used Visual Studio, most versions since version 6.0.  I just started getting the error

```
VC++ fatal error LNK1168: cannot open *filename*.exe for writing
```

on

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.1.3
```

There are several other questions on this forum asking in effect how to get rid of the error but the specific question allows for--and receives--manual solutions: manually close the debug output window, manually find the file and delete it, manually find in the task manager or resource monitor, manually reboot, etc. etc.

I am not asking what manual procedure makes this error go away.  Instead I am asking if there's a way or a convenient Visual Studio procedure to avoid having the error in the first place, for instance to have Visual Studio kill the binary on shift-F5 (Debug Stop) or recompile or some such.

I just started a little throwaway project.  It outputs to a terminal.  It hits a breakpoint or crashes.  I  fix the code and by reflex hit shift-F5 F5 (Debug Stop; Debug) as I think I've done for 25 years, and now am always getting this error, because I don't manually close the output window.  And I don't manually close the output window as I don't recall ever having to do so before.

Granted I normally write GUI programs or daemons, and this little program uses terminal output.  Is that the problem?

Or, is has it always been like this but I've somehow rebound shift-F5 to actually kill the process being debugged?

Or is there an Options to check so that shift-F5 also kills the binary?

Or is there an Options to check so that F5 kills the binary?

Or some alternate hotkey sequence I should be using after fixing a bug and wanting a recompile?

Or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the option (very near the bottom of the list) Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General-->Automatically close the console when debugging stops

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem on and off with VS Community 2022 on Win10.
The fix described here occasionally works for a while, but is a PITA
since it blows away diagnostic output on unexpected process exit.
Moreover, closing the console window manually does not release the lock.  The only reliable way to break the lock is to delete the .exe file.
What is really irritating is the inconsistency:  Some weeks I get the lock,
some not.  Rebooting sometimes makes it go away for a while, and sometimes
does not.  I always disable indexing and antivirus on my build directories,
but to no avail.  I really wish MS would look into this.

UPDATE:  this is apparently not a normal Windows file lock, as Process Explorer cannot find any process that is holding a lock. Killing the MSBuild process does not release it, nor does restarting Visual Studio. Rebooting Windows 10 usually fixes it for a few days or weeks.

UPDATE 2: Having same problem, even more regularly, on a newer machine running Windows 11.  It is not related to whether the process crashes or exits normally, and automatically closing the console window has no effect.  I strongly suspect a bug in VS 2022 and am outraged that MS has not issued a fix.

Answer (score 0):

It is a filesystem indexing issue: excluding the build directory from indexing -- both by Windows and by Everything -- fixes the problem.